# function with array in Fortran

Tags: arrays, function, fortran

Why will this not compile?

```
function rectangle() result(arr)
    real :: x1,x2,y1,y2
    real, dimension(4) :: arr
    x1=1; x2=3; y1=2; y2=8
    arr = [x1,x2,y1,y2]
end function 

program main
    real, dimension(4) :: b
    b=rectangle()        
end program
```

The error message is:

```
$gfortran -o rect2 rectTest2.f90
rectTest2.f90:10:15:

     b=rectangle()
               1
Error: Explicit interface required for ‘rectangle’ at (1): array result
```

When I move the function into the main program, with a "contains" statement, as shown below, it compiles and runs with no problem. Why?

```
program main
    real, dimension(4) :: b
    b=rectangle()  

    contains 
        function rectangle() result(arr)
            real :: x1,x2,y1,y2
            real, dimension(4) :: arr
            x1=1; x2=3; y1=2; y2=8
            arr = [x1,x2,y1,y2]
        end function 
      
end program
```

Comment: You need to read a Fortran reference about the requirements placed on an **implicit interface** and an **explicit interface**.  Your original code uses an implicit interface and is invalid Fortran.  The error message tells you that you need an explicit interface.  The second code with `contains` automatically created an explicit interface for you.

Comment: Just to expand a little bit, the hint in the error message is that you need an interface because your function returns an array rather than a simple scalar value. Change `b`, `arr` to simple scalars and assign `arr=x1` and all is fine. Not so with an array function.

Comment: But the best way to address this is to always put procedures in modules or as contained procedures. Then you need never worry about it

Comment: Thank you, evets, RussF, Ian Bush